# Notation to describe function which maps from natural numbers to set of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If $f$ is a function which maps natural numbers to natural numbers, we'd write $\;f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. But how would you say that $f$ maps from natural numbers to sets of natural numbers?

Answer (score 2):

$f:\Bbb N\to\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is the most usual way. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is the set of all subsets of $\Bbb N$.

$f\in\mathcal P(\Bbb N)^{\Bbb N}$ is also used. (If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $B^A$ usually means the set of functions from $A$ to $B$).

Comment: To the OP: re: the second notation, note that the number of functions from an $n$-element set to a $k$-element set is $k^n$ when $n, k$ are finite. So that's where that notation comes from.

Comment: Power set can also be denoted $2^\mathbb{N}$ as well - just in case someone encounters that. Cheers. (Motivation for this notation: A subset can be represented as a "binary string" (whether you can order it, visualize it or not hence the scare quotes) with one bit for each element of the whole set, a 1 bit tagging a member in the subset, and a 0 bit tagging a member not in the subset. Thus there should be $2^{|X|}$ possibilities so the notation $2^X$ for the power set of $X$. Essentially the same as the second notation in the post but used somewhat differently.)

Answer (score 0):

The power set is noted $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ it is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$.

So if you have a function from integers to integers this would be $f:\mathbb N\to A$ where $A\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, but this is the same as $A\subset \mathbb N$.

And if you have a function from integers to sets this would be $f:\mathbb N\to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.